# Filter collection based on values in another collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of ints and a list of objects which contain int IDs.

If the array of ints contains 1,2, 3 etc, I just want to get the objects which contain those IDs (So those with 1, 2, 3, etc).

How could this be done in .NET 3.5?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DaveShaw's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9634531/414076) is fine if you are dealing with small sequences. If your array of IDs grows larger, a more performant approach would be to load the array into a `HashSet<T>` and then perform the exact same query, except using the set instead.

```
var hashset = new HashSet<int>(ints);
var matches = objects.Where(obj => hashset.Contains(obj.Id));
```

For this and other more complicated scenarios, you should also know about `Enumerable.Join` that matches two sequences based upon keys and yields the desired results.

```
 var matches = from obj in objects 
               join id in ints
               on obj.Id equals id
               select obj;
 // var matches = objects.Join(ints, obj => obj.Id, id => id, (obj, id) => obj);
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `objects` is a list of instances of your class that have an `Id` property, you can do it like this.

```
var ints = new[] {1, 2, 3, };
var matches = objects.Where(obj => ints.Contains(obj.Id));
```

Answer (score -1):

An alternative to [the where approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9634531/17493) might be something like this:

```
var ints = new[] {1, 2, 3, };
var matches = ints.Intersect(objects.Select( obj => obj.Id));
```

This projects the objects to ints, and then performs the Intersect Set operation. Just a different approach.

Comment: Doesn't this return a collection of ids as opposed to a collection of objects?

Comment: Also, .Contains() on an Array should be more efficient than an .Intersect(), because it doesn't need to create a new Set for the results.